# Disable hostname verification in wildfly

Tags: ssl, wildfly, cas, jasig

I've tried so set **org.jboss.security.ignoreHttpsHost** property to disable hostname verification with WILDFLY but it doesn't work.

Any hint?

Comment: Disable for what? what part of server? your code that runs inside? what is that code?

Comment: Thanks for your reply ctomc. In fact i'm trying to integrate Jasig CAS (SSO) in an app deployed in wildfly and i have issue with ssl certificate when CN doesn't match machine name. And i have this problem with Wildfly only, it works with tomcat. That's why i need to tell Wildfly to disable hostname check for SSL certificates. Thanks